Different performance on 2 database tables
I have two tables with the following definitions
create table rdm
(
    id                integer                        not null,
    fk_plc            integer                        not null,
    booklet_sequence  smallint                       not null,
    payment_sequence  smallint                       not null,
    due_date          date                           not null,
    amount            bigint                         not null,
    save_amount       bigint                         not null,
    amount            bigint                         not null,
    fk_plc_delete     integer sparse,
    fk_lpy_delete     integer sparse,
    etl_date          datetime default sysdatetime() not null,
    constraint pk_rdm primary key (id),
    constraint uk_rdm_payment_sequence unique (fk_plc, payment_sequence)
);

alter table rdm add constraint fk_rdm_plc foreign key (fk_plc) references plc(id);
alter table rdm add constraint fk_rdm_plc_delete foreign key (fk_plc_delete) references plc(id);
create index ix_rdm_plc_delete on rdm (fk_plc_delete);

and
create table plb
(
    id             integer                        not null,
    operation_date date                           not null,
    amount         bigint                         not null,
    fk_pbt         integer                        not null,
    fk_plc         integer                        not null,
    fk_rdm         integer,
    fk_lpy         integer sparse,
    cover_end_date date,
    fk_plb_cancel  integer sparse,
    etl_date       datetime default sysdatetime() not null,
    constraint pk_plb primary key (id)
);

alter table plb  add constraint fk_plb_plc foreign key (fk_plc) references plc (id);
create index ix_plb_plc on plb (fk_plc);

alter table plb add constraint fk_plb_rdm foreign key (fk_rdm) references rdm (id);
create index ix_plc_rdm on plb (fk_rdm);

alter table plb add constraint fk_plb_lpy foreign key (fk_lpy) references lpy(id);
create index ix_plc_lpy on plb (fk_lpy);

alter table plb add constraint fk_plb_plb_cancel foreign key (fk_plb_cancel) references plb (id);

alter table plb nocheck constraint fk_plb_plb_cancel;
create index ix_plc_plb_cancel on plb (fk_plb_cancel);

alter table plb add constraint ck_plb_pbt check (fk_pbt in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));
alter table plb add constraint fk_plb_pbt foreign key (fk_pbt) references plb_type (id);
alter table plb nocheck constraint fk_plb_pbt;

they are stored in same the database, same filegroup, same resources.
I am filling them with batch inserts of 1000 records.
The strange thing is that the first table gets filled at a rate of almost 30k records per second, but the second one with less than 1k records per second. The first table will have 1.4m record after the ETL process, but the second one just 108k. But the ETL of the second table takes more time.
I am using Apache NIFI to do the ETL job, and they both have exactly the same flow (in fact same parameterized flow).
As I was inspecting things in NIFI, the insert operation on the second table is much slower.
So I wonder why that is? Is there anything missed from my eyes in these declarations?
I was suspicious on second table's self-reference, so I disabled its checking, nothing improved. Even dropping that constraints doesn't change a thing.

At first glance, the 2nd table has a lot more constraints and indexes which could slow things down. If you are sure there are no violations during the inserts then you could wait with adding them until after the inserts.

No violation happens, and all rows get inserted, but the speed rate difference is so high.... around 30 times...

I agree that I'd try to rip all constraints off both tables to see if their insert rate is similar and if so, then keep retesting by adding a constraint at a time as that's the only obviously suspicious thing I can see at a quick glance.
